# Why was my system adminstration question migrated away to Stackoverflow so that it could be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575531/can-i-add-new-shared-directories-to-docker-from-the-command-line

This isn't a software development, programming, or software engineering/architecture issue.

It seems malicious. The effect is certainly so, even if the intent wasn't there.

Docker is used to deploy already-written software, that's its primary purpose. Is it not on-topic here?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have closed this as "unclear what you are asking", because your question is just that - very unclear. You don't talk about your environment, your purpose, what exactly you tried and how exactly that failed - "it barfs" is by no means an acceptable error description here. Also, you  added a screenshot about Docker for Mac, which is decidedly a *development* environment not meant for production use (any dev environments/purposes are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF]).

Comment: The migration was decidedly not malicious. Would have you rather I just closed it altogether?

Comment: "*Docker is used to deploy already-written software, that's its primary purpose*" well, that sums up my problems with docker in a single line very nicely.  Not only is that not its primary purpose, it really, *really* shouldn't be used for that.

Answer (score 4):

Sven's comment above sums up why I migrated it. You're using a development tool, which is used much more frequently by SO folks than SF folks. So not only is your question off-topic *here*, but it stands a better chance of being answered *there*. So in that regard, you're in a better situation now than if your question was left here.

If you'd been asking about general docker engine use, from the command-line, on a Linux server, the question would be on-topic here.

I would like to address your below comment about this not being a development tool. To do so, I'll quote from Docker's [website](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac), emphasis mine:

> Docker for Mac is an easy-to-install desktop app for building,
>   debugging and testing Dockerized apps on a Mac. **Docker for Mac is a
>   complete development environment deeply integrated with the MacOS
>   Hypervisor framework, networking and filesystem.** Docker for Mac is
>   the fastest and most reliable way to run Docker on a Mac.

Comment: It's not even slightly a development tool. It doesn't compile, it doesn't let you edit, debug, or do any of the other things that is development. It lets you deploy already written, complete software packages... 100% system administration. That's its primary use. In that a software developer is supposed to finish a software product and provide it in usable form to other people, it's slightly associated with development... but in that sense, so is all modern software. I challenge anyone to explain how I am wrong in this.

Comment: @JohnO: Context matters. [SF] exclusively cares about production use. If your use case is developing or testing (Docker is often used for this and it's the only viable use for Docker/Mac to begin with), your question is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and [SO] is a better place for it as that site also deals with dev tools in general. If your use case is production use, you should have made that clear.

Comment: @JohnO Please see my edit. You are free to continue thinking that this is not a development tool, but that flies in the face of all evidence **and** vendor documentation on the product.

Comment: @JohnO Also, I'll reiterate something I think you perhaps missed from above: Docker for Mac is expressly designed for dev usage. The docker engine, however, is perfectly suited for production. I've been using it in this capacity for years. There is a huge difference between these two products, though, including how one interacts with them. "File sharing" plain and simple is not a thing with properly-designed production docker systems. Nor is a GUI management layer.